# Assigning value to selected dropdown tab

Tags: jquery, html, css, drop-down-menu

I am new to building web pages and would welcome any recommendations on how to create a simple drop down tab whose selection appears in the button itself and whose selection is attributed a value.

In the example below, when hovering over `Dropdown`, three choices appear - link 1, link 2, or link 3.  How would one change the text of "Dropdown" to that of 'link 1' when `link 1` is selected, and to give `link 1` a value of 1, `link 2` a value of 2, and so on?

My objective is to write an simple if/else statement based on the value displayed in the dropdown menu. So for example

```
    dropdownValue = document.getElementById('dropdown-menu')
    if (dropdownValue === 1) {
        console.log('yes')
    }
    else if (dropdownValue === 2) {
        console.log('no')
    }
    else {
        console.log('maybe')
    };
```

**CSS:**

```
.dropbtn {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 38px;
    line-height: 28px;
    padding: 16px;
    font-size: 16px;
    border: 1px solid white;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 16px;
    margin-right: 5px;
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    padding: 5px 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.dropdown {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #f1f1f1}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
    background-color: #3e8e41;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
  <div class="dropdown">
      <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
      <div class="dropdown-content">
          <a href="#">Link 1</a>
          <a href="#">Link 2</a>
          <a href="#">Link 3</a>
      </div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/cp9cw3ph/#

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a `click` event listener to the links and use `textContent` or `innerHTML` to get the content in the link and apply it to the button.

```js
var btn = document.getElementById('dropbtn'),
  links = document.getElementById('dropdown-content').getElementsByTagName('a');

for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
 links[i].addEventListener('click',function() {
   btn.textContent = this.textContent;
  })
}
```

```css
.dropbtn {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 38px;
    line-height: 28px;
    padding: 16px;
    font-size: 16px;
    border: 1px solid white;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 16px;
    margin-right: 5px;
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    padding: 5px 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.dropdown {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #f1f1f1}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
    background-color: #3e8e41;
}
```

```html
  <div class="dropdown">
  <button class="dropbtn" id="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
  <div class="dropdown-content" id="dropdown-content">
    <a href="#">Link 1</a>
    <a href="#">Link 2</a>
    <a href="#">Link 3</a>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this JQuery code:

```
$(function(){
    $("a").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(".dropbtn").html($(this).html());
        switch ($(this).attr("_value")){
            case "1":
                console.log("yes");
            break;
            case "2":
                console.log("no");
            break;
            case "3":
                console.log("maybe");
            break;
        }

    });

});
```

**HTML:**

```
  <div class="dropdown">
  <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="#" _value="1">Link 1</a>
    <a href="#" _value="2">Link 2</a>
    <a href="#" _value="3">Link 3</a>
  </div>
```